# Not able to get data from cursor in oracle

Tags: asp.net, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to get data from oracle database using asp.net but I am not getting any output in cursor while data is present in table:
I am using following stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE branch_details
( startIndex in  int
,pageSize    in  int
,isSearch    in  int
,byName      in  int
,dataDetail  in  varchar2
, p_cursor   out sys_refcursor)
AS
BEGIN
    IF isSearch=1 THEN
        IF byName=1 THEN
          OPEN p_cursor FOR
          SELECT *
            FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY branch_id)
                         AS MyRows
                       , branch_id, branch_name
                       , branch_location, bm_name, bm_contact
                       , bm_email, is_active, max_ua
                       , (SELECT COUNT(branch_id)
                            FROM branch_info
                           WHERE branch_name LIKE
                                 '%'|| dataDetail||'%')
                         AS RowNumber
                    FROM branch_info 
                   WHERE branch_name LIKE '%'|| dataDetail||'%')
           WHERE MyRows BETWEEN startIndex
                                 AND startIndex+pageSize-1;
        ELSE
          OPEN p_cursor FOR
          SELECT *
            FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY branch_id)
                         AS MyRows
                       , branch_id, branch_name, branch_location
                       , bm_name, bm_contact, bm_email, is_active
                       , max_ua
                       , (SELECT COUNT(branch_id)
                            FROM branch_info
                           WHERE branch_id LIKE
                                 '%'|| dataDetail||'%')
                         As  RowNumber 
                    FROM branch_info 
                   WHERE branch_id LIKE '%'|| dataDetail||'%')
           WHERE MyRows BETWEEN startIndex
                            AND startIndex+pageSize-1;
        END IF;
    ELSE
        OPEN p_cursor FOR
        SELECT *
          FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY branch_id)
                         AS MyRows
                     , branch_id, branch_name, branch_location
                     , bm_name, bm_contact, bm_email
                     , is_active, max_ua
                     , (SELECT COUNT(branch_id)
                          FROM branch_info) AS RowNumber 
                  FROM branch_info)
         WHERE MyRows BETWEEN startIndex
                          AND startIndex+pageSize-1;
    END IF;
END;
```

And using following asp.net code:

```
List<Paramarray> param = new List<Paramarray>();
    param.Add(new Paramarray("@dataDetail", data));
    param.Add(new Paramarray("@byName", id?"0":"1"));
    param.Add(new Paramarray("@isSearch", isSearch?"1":"0"));
    param.Add(new Paramarray("@startIndex", startIndex==1?startIndex.ToString():Convert.ToString(((startIndex-1)*pageSize)+1)));
    param.Add(new Paramarray("@pageSize", pageSize.ToString()));

    _command.Connection = _connection;
    _command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    _command.CommandText = "branch_details";
    foreach (Paramarray _param in param)
    {
        _parameter = new OracleParameter(_param.name,_param.value);
        _command.Parameters.Add(_parameter);            
    }

    _command.Parameters.Add("@p_cursor", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    if (_connection.State != ConnectionState.Open) _connection.Open();
    _dataReader = _command.ExecuteReader();
    dt.Load(_dataReader);
    if (_connection.State == ConnectionState.Open) _connection.Close();
```

My same code for another procedure is working fine and giving me output.

Please help me if I am wrong in my procedure or somewhere else. I am not able to figure the problem.

Comment: Your ASP code appears to be calling a procedure called `log_details`.  You posted the implementation of the `branch_details` procedure which takes a different set of arguments.

Comment: @JustinCave sorry for incorrect uploading please check my updated questions.

Comment: Do you know if the procedure returns results if executed in the DB?

Comment: Are you sure that the `isSearch` parameter is equal to 1 when this procedure is called?

Comment: @BobJarvis no isSearch parameter is 0 which will take code into else condition.

Comment: Sorry - didn't scroll far enough.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to wager that your procedure is wrong.  Your asp.net code looks fine and without more information it seems to me that the cursor is just not returning any data.

Have you unit tested the procedure or even just the cursor queries?